# Access contact PhotoURL images when not logged into Salesforce

Tags: rest-api

I've connected to Salesforce via REST and am querying the photoURL field of the contact record.  I get back something like this for the photoURL
/services/images/photo/0030N000024o75dQAA

On the client side, which is a web application, I add that value to the org instance URL and get
https://eu8.salesforce.com/services/images/photo/0030N000024o75dQAA

We use that in an image tag on the web page and it redirects the image to the social media site:
https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/479287176824233984/jxCcTken_bigger.jpeg

To put it another way

```
<img src="https://eu8.salesforce.com/services/images/photo/0030N000024o75dQAA"/>
```

will 302 redirect the image to that from twitter.

All great **IF you are logged into Salesforce** in the browser.  As the information is being accessed via REST from an external webpage to Salesforce then this is not going to always be the case.  I.e. `<img src="https://eu8.salesforce.com/services/images/photo/0030N000024o75dQAA"/>` will be rejected by Salesforce as you're not logged in in the browser.

I did find an interesting solution where if I put an query string attribute of oauth_token with the call to API call to Salesforce

```
<img src="https://eu8.salesforce.com/services/images/photo/0030N000024o75dQAA?oauth_token=xyz123etcetcetc"/>
```

then Salesforce let's it in and sends back the 302 redirect and the browser displays the twitter image.  I was happy.

However Salesforce's Enterprise Security team did a review on the application and they asked for this to be removed.

So, my question.  Given an application running in a browser that uses REST/OAuth2 to communicate with Salesforce how do I get it to render the social media images associated with a contact when the browser is not logged into Salesforce and Salesforce security reject the ?oauth_token approach?